# What are the possible ways I can handle duplicate data in ADX

Tags: azure, kql, azure-data-explorer, adx

There are common ways to handle dup data as described [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/dealing-with-duplicates)

But I'm looking for more options.
Thanks

I have tried the options from here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/dealing-with-duplicates
and was looking into unique hashed row approach or a policy which triggers the function and periodic KQL queries to identify and remove the duplicate data.

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm looking for more options

Another approach to handle duplicate data in ADX is by using `distinct`. It removes the duplicate data from the table.

Below is the sample table `TableF` is created with duplicate data as shown below.
[image]

Use below query with `distinct` to work with duplicate values. It stores the data in another table `newTable`

```sql
let newTable = TableF
| distinct *;
newTable
```

**Output:**
[image]